# Vanishing of Chern-Simons invariant

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

I am computing Chern-Simons invariants using the metric given by the Bianchi Types, associated naturally to seven of the eight Thurston geometries. However, many of them result to be identically zero. Since I am just testing my code, I am not sure if this is a correct result. I only have that the code does compute correctly the invariant for $\mathbb{S}^3$ with its standard metric, but I do not have other results for 3-mflds to really check if my code works. Would there be any reason to believe this vanishing is true? Especially that $\mathbb{H}^3$, and $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ with their std metrics by Bianchi classification turn out to have invariant $\Phi = 0$.

Comment: Chern-Simons compute the invariant for the (bi-)invariant metric on $SO(3)$ and get $1/2$. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I do get that for $SO(3)$

Comment: One big result from their original paper (Thm 6.4 there): A necessary condition that M admit a conformal immersion in $R^4$ is that $\Phi(M)=0$.  This probably doesn't help you here, unfortunately, but I mention it because it could alert you to an error in your code if you compute a non-zero $\Phi$ for a manifold which you know admits a conformal immersion in $R^4$.